# ASP.NET 5 Google OAuth logins expiring

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, google-signin

I have followed the steps on [MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) for creating a Google OAuth external login.

However, periodically, my user's logins are not working. They have to log into their account with a password and remove, then re-add their external login for it to work again. However, it will fail again after a certain period of time.

Is there something this tutorial doesn't cover? Why are my Google logins expiring?

EDIT: I am not using refresh tokens. I am now asking for "offline" access. All I need is communication at time of the sign on.

It seems as if the following code is returning NULL for Google after some time.

```
 var loginInfo = await _authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
 if (loginInfo == null)
 {
     return RedirectToAction("Login");
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google OAuth access token expiration in MVC app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678496/google-oauth-access-token-expiration-in-mvc-app)

Comment: @StaffordWilliams, I don't need a refresh token. All I need is access to their account at time of signin. The question you linked to is about incremental authentication for offline access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be with the OAuth middleware and custom session state providers. Turns out, you can't get a valid `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` result without a session cookie being present. God knows how they are related, but there is a simple hack to fix it.

[OAuth 2 Owin not working StackExchange.Redis SessionState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725206/oauth-2-owin-not-working-stackexchange-redis-sessionstate)